# What does the phrase "Have weight to " mean?

Tags: slang

I've watched a TV show about house renovation.
After they take down a old window and carry it away. A guy says something like:

> It was a decent window. Jeepers have some weight to it

What does this phrase mean in this context?

Comment: I thought better of posting as an answer so I attempted to delete - I was only trying to clarify and augment the answer that Robbie_R gave you. He was before me and deserves the points for a selected answer. Please try to uncheck my answer and select Robbie_R.

Comment: Done! I really like the atmosphere here

Comment: Could it have been _It was a decent window. Jeepers – it has some weight to it!_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you must be right. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have some substance to it.

In this context, if it is a wood window, better quality timbers will be more dense, therefore heavier. Even a pine window will come in a range of densities with heavier woods seen as better for the purpose.

http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick answer, it makes sense, could you explain the structure to me more: somebody have some weight to the window, I don't the weight of the window has anything to do with the person that is Jeepers

Comment: Is there really a person named Jeepers on the show? "Jeepers" is also an old exclamation that expresses surprise.

Comment: Yes, it sounds to me like an expression of surprise at being caught out by the weight of the window.

Comment: +1 Robbie - **"Jeepers!"** is a shortened form of the vernacular introjection: Jeepers Creepers. The Urban Dictionary has this: **jeepers creepers**: 1) intj. An expression of extreme surprise. Derived from "**J**esus **C**hrist". "**have some weight to it": you probably misheard or mistyped, the commom phrase is "has some weight to it" i.e., "this window frame is much heavier than I expected!"

Comment: It *is* a name and the name is Jesus Christ - rendered as jeepers creepers (JC) it is a method of not "taking the Lord's name in vain."

Comment: Sorry Robbie, I added as an answer what you see in the comment above but I realized you had answered good enough and deleted my answer and re-posted it as comment - somehow my delete didn't take and the answer remained. I apologize I didn't mean to crowd you out.

Comment: No offence taken whatsoever. The more, the merrier to use an old-fashioned saying:) Wasn't aware of the Jeepers Creepers/Jesus Christ* association, so thank you! *apart from the original song http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_%28song%29

Answer (score 3):

**"Jeepers!"** is a shortened form of the vernacular introjection: Jeepers Creepers

The Urban Dictionary has this:

> **jeepers creepers**: 1) intj. An expression of extreme surprise. Derived from "**J**esus **C**hrist"
>
> "**have some weight to it**": you probably misheard or mistyped, the commom phrase is "has some weight to it" i.e., "this window frame is much heavier than I expected!"